# Two dependent inputs in a form

Tags: forms

I have a form where the user would need to input a text field, and then enter pricing based on the first input. I've come up with an idea on how to do this, but not sure if its the best approach:

[image]

Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you let us know more about the task the user needs to perform? I mean the bigger picture.

Comment: How many sizes can be there ?

Comment: Its a form restaurant owners are filling out to enter their menu items. So its basically about a menu item, say pizza, and sizes are probably not more than 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks workable, and like a logical approach. Of course, the best way to tell would be to test it, even with just one or two restaurant owners.

Could potentially be improved by hiding the price field until a size is chosen. This will help communicate the dependency between the two fields.

Depending on how the rest of the application is designed, it might also make the owner's job easier if you let them select sizes for a whole number of items at once, e.g. use the interface to select a group of pizzas and say the sizes for all these pizzas are small, medium and large. Similarly, it might be good to allow them to set a default price per size (e.g. default price for small is $10) but allow this to be overwritten on a pizza-by-size basis.

Comment: I was exactly thinking about the same problem. A lot of menu sections have the same pricing, that'd save a lot of keystrokes. Thankyou.